# Permission Denied using Google AiPlatform ModelServiceClient

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, model, google-ai-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am following a guide to get a Vertex AI pipeline working:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/vertex-pipelines-intro#5

I have implemented the following custom component:

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform as aip
from google.oauth2 import service_account

project = "project-id"
region = "us-central1"
display_name = "lookalike_model_pipeline_1646929843"

model_name = f"projects/{project}/locations/{region}/models/{display_name}"
api_endpoint = "us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com" #europe-west2
model_resource_path = model_name
client_options = {"api_endpoint": api_endpoint}

# Initialize client that will be used to create and send requests.
client = aip.gapic.ModelServiceClient(credentials=service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('..\\service_accounts\\aiplatform_sa.json'), 
client_options=client_options)
#get model evaluation
response = client.list_model_evaluations(parent=model_name)
```

And I get following error:

```
(<class 'google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied'>, PermissionDenied("Permission 'aiplatform.modelEvaluations.list' denied on resource '//aiplatform.googleapis.com/projects/project-id/locations/us-central1/models/lookalike_model_pipeline_1646929843' (or it may not exist)."), <traceback object at 0x000002414D06B9C0>)
```

The model definitely exists and has finished training. I have given myself admin rights in the aiplatform service account. In the guide, they do not use a service account, but uses only client_options instead. The client_option has the wrong type since it is a dict(str, str) when it should be: Optional['ClientOptions']. But this doesn't cause an error.

My main question is: how do I get around this permission issue?

My subquestions are:

1. How can I use my model_name variable in a URL to get to the model?
2. How can I create an Optional['ClientOptions'] object to pass as client_option
3. Is there another way I can list_model_evaluations from a model that is in VertexAI, trained using automl?

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you (a) demonstrate that it "definitely" works by including perhaps a `gcloud` command that enumerates the model in `us-central1; (b) explain what roles/permissions you assigned to the service account. It's much easier to use Application Default Credentials `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/your/key.json` than reference keys in code.

Comment: `aip.gapic.ModelServiceClient` is unusual but it evidently works.It's helpful for others to hyperlink to references like that in your question. I'll Google it.

Comment: Where (I can't find it) does the documentation tell you to override the API endpoint?

Comment: @DazWilkin to your first comment:
How can I do that? All I can tell you is that when I go to VertexAi, go to Models, it says that: lookalike_model_pipeline_1646929843 is ready and was created. I made the service account and gave myself owner and service account admin privileges.

Comment: 2nd comment:
In some code I wrote before, I used:                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                      
    for model in table_client.list_models():

        model_eval_response = table_client.list_model_evaluations(
            model_name=model.name)
                                                                                                  which worked

Comment: Third comment:

the link above created api_enpoint in the way previously mentioned. I realised after debugging that the object type was wrong, but it doesnt seem to cause the code to error.

I could privately message you with more info if you like. The guide is clearly outdated.

Comment: I'm very familiar with GCP but no with the AI|ML stuff (the naming is confusing!). There are 2 flavors of SDK (the older, all-Google API Clients) and the Cloud only Cloud Clients. I recommend using the Cloud Client, see: https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried using your code and it did not also work for me and got a different error. As @DazWilkin mentioned it is recommended to use the Cloud Client.

I used `aiplatform_v1` and it worked fine. One thing I noticed is that you should always define a value for `client_options` so it will point to the correct endpoint. Checking the code for [ModelServiceClient](https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform/blob/main/google/cloud/aiplatform_v1/services/model_service/client.py#L122), if I'm not mistaken the endpoint defaults to **"aiplatform.googleapis.com"** which don't have a location prepended. AFAIK the endpoint should prepend a [location](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/locations).

See code below. I used AutoML models and it returns their model evaluations.

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform_v1 as aiplatform
from typing import Optional

def get_model_eval(
        project_id: str,
        model_id: str,
        client_options: dict,
        location: str = 'us-central1',
        ):

    client_model = aiplatform.services.model_service.ModelServiceClient(client_options=client_options)

    model_name = f'projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}/models/{model_id}'
    list_eval_request = aiplatform.types.ListModelEvaluationsRequest(parent=model_name)
    list_eval = client_model.list_model_evaluations(request=list_eval_request)
    print(list_eval)



api_endpoint = 'us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com'
client_options = {"api_endpoint": api_endpoint} # api_endpoint is required for client_options
project_id = 'project-id'
location = 'us-central1'
model_id = '99999999999' # aiplatform_v1 uses the model_id

get_model_eval(
        client_options = client_options,
        project_id = project_id,
        location = location,
        model_id = model_id,
        )
```

This is an output snippet from my AutoML Text Classification:

[image]

Comment: What version of google.cloud.aiplatform do you have? aiplatform.services does not exist for me and I have 1.10.0

Comment: @scottlucas I'm using `google-cloud-aiplatform==1.11.0`. I added my imports as well.

Comment: The issue was that I was not using project and model id, I was using their display names

Comment: Calling it from `aiplatform.services` is kinda counterintuitive, thanks for pointing this out!